# Using vectors in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

Is there a way to define *vectors* in TikZ? By that I mean the ability to add and scalar multiply coordinate tuples, for example for drawing a parallelogram:

```
% Just pseudocode:
P := (0,1);
Q := (1,1);
\draw[-] (0,0) -- P -- (P+Q) -- Q -- (0,0);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Coordinates are already some kind of vectors. Library `calc` provides the addition of coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw
  (0, 1) coordinate (P)
  (1, 1) coordinate (Q)
  (0, 0) -- (P) -- ($(P) + (Q)$) -- (Q) -- cycle
;
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

BTW: Closed paths should use `cycle` to get a proper line join at the starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is an excellent answer! Also thanks for the `cycle` hint!

Comment: A follow up question: Is there some way to use the defined `P` and `Q` in more than one (that particular) `\draw` command?

Comment: @flawr For more than one `\draw` command, use environment use environment `tikzpicture`.